# fast search and replace in xml files (dreamweaver features similar)

Tags: xml, search, replace, editor, dreamweaver

I would like to know if there is an xml editor with xml searching and replacing features similar to dreamweaver ones,  in which you can search and replace in directories for specific tag with specific attributes or containing specific text and so on.

Dreamweaver is very slow in these features.

I have also searched suggestions in this site, trying notepad++ xml plugin, Sublime Text 2 and Easy XML Editor, but none of these is ok.

Freeware would be preferable and I'm not interested in regular expression searches.

Thanks!

I edited this question including a sample image of dreamweaver search. 
As you can see, you can add multiple criteria and set different actions for all of your folder files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

- Eclipse
- Geany (native on Linux, on OS/X with Homebrew, somewhere is a Windows port too)
- Oxygen XML (commercial)
- XML Spy (commercial, Windows only)

You can't escape RegEx (but ignore it if not needed)

Comment: I have tried with your suggested options, but features are different. I have edited my post, including a sample image.